# z-index for the nested div

Tags: css, pug, scss-lint

I expect to get this result: 
https://ibb.co/htJD6J

In my styles I've set to the parent position relative; z-index 50. For the child I've set position absolute; z-index 25.
But as a result, I've got this.
 https://ibb.co/cwhjDy 
P.S. Sorry, not enough reputation to post images.
So, I can't understand why z-index isn't worked correctly.
Can anybody help me with it?

Add code:
parent

```
.sel_project_block {
 background-color: #f5876e;
 border-radius: 14px;
 margin-right: 150px;
 width: 239px;
 height: 34px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-end;
 align-items: center;
 position: relative;
 box-shadow: 1px 3px 7px #000;
 z-index: 5;
}
```

child

```
.additional {
 max-width: 185px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 76.2%;
 right: 22.05%;
 z-index: 1;
 color: #67573e;
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #978d7e;
 font-size: 16px;
 width: 185px;
}
```

Comment: We don't need images, but your code.

Comment: change position to absolute and add negative z index, margin as needed

Comment: karthik, if you can see - I use relative/absolute position and z-indexes, but the not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `.child` is relative to its `.parent`, so does its z-index.

You can do away with this by removing the `z-index` of the parent:

```css
.sel_project_block {
  background-color: #f5876e;
  border-radius: 14px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  width: 239px;
  height: 34px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 7px #000;
}

.additional {
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 185px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 76.2%;
  right: 22.05%;
  z-index: -1;
  color: #67573e;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #978d7e;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 185px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sel_project_block">
  <div class="additional"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll try it and answer you next day. Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `position: anything-that-is-not-static` establishes a new stacking context.

The position of the child element is **with respect to the parent** (that is `position: relative`).

So if you want it to appear *behind* the parent, you have to give it a **negative** `z-index`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `div#child` is a child element of `div#parent`, and since `div#parent` establishes a stacking context (because it has an integer z-index value), you can't put `div#parent` on top of `div#child` by increasing its z-index

The z-index you set for `div#child` is within the context of `div#parent`. So if you want `div#child` to appear below `div#parent` you need to set a negative z-index for `div#child`.

in the future - if you post code to accompany your question the answers would be easier to understand. (also, properly asking a question will yield better results as well)

Comment: but what?? I'm confused at what you are getting at here

Answer (score 0):

Ok, colleagues. After a few hours, I solve my problems.
What I'd done:
at first, I added new wrapper and put all blocks include parent and child in it.
at second, I added to the wrapper block z-index = 3; and set to the dropdown block z-index = -1.
It seems in pug:

```
.dropdownWrapper
 .sel_project_block
 .sel_project_block__proj
   span New Project
.sel_project_block__imgWrapper(@click="showDropdown")
  img(src="../assets/images/white-arrow.png")
.clientsTop__dropdown
.additional(v-if="dropdownVisible")
.first {{ newProject.trans }}
```

...

and scss code:

```
.dropdownWrapper {
height: 34px;
width: 239px;
margin-right: 50px;
z-index: 3;
position: relative;

.sel_project_block {
  ...
}

.clientsTop__dropdown {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 59.2%;
  right: 13.8%;
...

  .additional {
    ...
  }
}
```

}